# Any security risk publicly posting a wildcard Certificate Authority and its key

Tags: ca

A wildcard CA and the associated key was posted company wide.  Is there any risk sharing this information inside and outside the company?

Comment: The private key or the public key?

Comment: If the private key is leaked, the SSL certificate is effectively meaningless -- anyone who has it can decrypt the encrypted traffic.  This question is better suited for `security.stackexchange.com` or `serverfault.com` though.  It's not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

If the *private* key was published: Revoke the CA immediately! (Unless you intend for any employee at the company to be able to create certificates.) If you are in the business of selling certificates: I would never purchase a certificate from a company where all the employees have the private key.

If the *public* key was published: No problem; as a matter of fact, publishing of the public key is a necessary part of using the certificate.